# Buck / Buck Boost converter as a regulator or rectifier question

Tags: voltage-regulator, battery-charging, switch-mode-power-supply, rectifier, switching-regulator

I have an older boat with a rectifier like https://www.ebay.com/itm/282755134541 . I understand that these will output 14-17V+ DC. With an increase in RPMs, I understand that the DC voltage increases. Using a regulator would protect the battery. This article gave me some ideas regarding these components https://electronicsclub.info/powersupplies.htm . I believe the AC input into the rectifier is almost always higher than the DC voltage. (perhaps boost is not necessary)

Furthermore, I think there are more expensive units that have a regulator built in. The following is a NOS regulated rectifier for my boat: https://www.ebay.com/itm/403527423281 . I think most of the regulated rectifiers for my boat are at least still designed using the same principles of that device. Then they look to be a design from perhaps 50+ years ago. (My outboard was itself manufactured in 1983).

I also think that regulator technology is advancing, and purchasing legacy components for an old outboard might not incorporate more recent advances in microelectronics.

This is what I gathered including reading this article: https://www.ultralibrarian.com/2020/08/04/comparing-a-step-down-converter-vs-voltage-regulator-ulc

I am now about to replace my rectifier. Could I use a Buck / Buck Boost converter as a regulator, after the rectifier?

After thinking along these lines, and assuming that I'm probably producing around 120W max, I think I would need a waterproof (epoxy potted or similar) buck boost converter. But after looking around it seems like the following device takes this a step further.

https://www.aliexpress.us/item/3256805095732020.html . This unit seems like it might be a good replacement, with the exception that the output is 12V vs ~14V DC. It also looks like it has two lines in for AC power, similar to the rectifier above. Looks like they give some idea how it is built.

Does anyone know what TI component might be used for the 10A version of this?

Is anyone familiar with a similar product that might output ~14V DC?

I must admit I'm tempted to buy one of these just to fiddle with it.

Comment: It looks like you are dealing with the charging system of an outboard motor, so you should stick with components designed for that purpose.  The Aliexpress device you linked definitely won't work for your application.  The original "rectifier" probably includes a voltage regulator function.

Comment: This is just a warning to not to rely on components purchased from Ali-express. If you need reliabily, buy from a reputable supplier. I will leave it to you to judge how reliable you need your electrical power on your boat.

Comment: A fixed output voltage of 12 V will not properly charge your battery. If this is a lead acid battery, 13.8 V would be acceptable.

Comment: > The original "rectifier" probably includes a voltage regulator function. 

```
It does not, and it's common knowledge to folks that are familiar with these motors: continuouswave.com/ubb/Forum6/HTML/002256.html . As mentioned in the post there are aftermarket parts that do include that.
```

Comment: > I will leave it to you to judge how reliable you need your electrical power on your boat. 



```
My rectifier hasn't worked since I owned the boat. It seems they are failure prone. I charge the battery occasionally on shore power. So I was looking at this to perhaps fiddle around with electronics.
```

Comment: > A fixed output voltage of 12 V will not properly charge your battery. If this is a lead acid battery, 13.8 V would be acceptable

```
I think I alluded to that by mentioning (12V vs ~14V) and asked about a similar product that output ~14V.
```